# MSDeploy reporting "could not find file" when using setParamFile

Tags: powershell, msdeploy

I'm using MSDeploy as part of a custom task in TFS2017 (Update 1) but I can't get the setParamFile option to work. It throws one of two errors.  If I specify no path, it says "could not find file" (see trace below). If I specify the path to the file on the build machine, it says invalid path.

I'm sure it's something incredibly simply but it's got me beat and Google is, for once, not being my friend! Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have provided the log unaltered as all this is only on internal servers. Without the setParamFile parameter, it deploys fine without updating the variable connection strings I'm trying to update, obviously.

`2017-04-15T22:41:13.5065833Z Executing the powershell script: D:\BuildAgent\tasks\MSDeployPackageMultiSync\1.1.16\MSDeployPackageSync.ps1
2017-04-15T22:41:13.6472111Z packageFile= Find-Files -SearchPattern D:\BuildAgent\_work\194fdc7b9\Data Collection App - Release\drop\_PublishedWebsites\Cabi.FormsAdmin.Api_Package\DCA_API.zip
2017-04-15T22:41:13.6472111Z packageFile= D:\BuildAgent\_work\194fdc7b9\Data Collection App - Release\drop\_PublishedWebsites\Cabi.FormsAdmin.Api_Package\DCA_API.zip
2017-04-15T22:41:13.6784674Z DCA_API.SetParameters.xml
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7097114Z Package= D:\BuildAgent\_work\194fdc7b9\Data Collection App - Release\drop\_PublishedWebsites\Cabi.FormsAdmin.Api_Package\DCA_API.zip
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7097114Z ParamFile= -setParamFile:'DCA_API.SetParameters.xml'
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7097114Z DestinationProvider= auto
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7097114Z DestinationComputer= prerelweb3,prerelweb4
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7097114Z Username= 
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7097114Z AdditionalArguments= 
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7253453Z Deploying  package to prerelweb3,prerelweb4
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7253453Z Deploying to prerelweb3
2017-04-15T22:41:13.7253453Z "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\BuildAgent\_work\194fdc7b9\Data Collection App - Release\drop\_PublishedWebsites\Cabi.FormsAdmin.Api_Package\DCA_API.zip' -setParamFile:'DCA_API.SetParameters.xml' -dest:auto,computerName='prerelweb3',userName='',password='',authType='ntlm',includeAcls='False' -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='WebServices (Secure)\FormsAdmin' -setParam:kind=DestinationVirtualDirectory,scope='WebServices (Secure)\\FormsAdmin',value='e:\cabi_sites\WebServices_Secure\FormsAdmin'  -allowUntrusted 
**2017-04-15T22:41:14.1315861Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Error: Could not find file ''DCA_API.SetParameters.xml''.**
2017-04-15T22:41:14.1315861Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Error count: 1.
2017-04-15T22:41:14.1315861Z Deployment to prerelweb3 complete
2017-04-15T22:41:14.1315861Z Deploying to prerelweb4
2017-04-15T22:41:14.1315861Z "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\BuildAgent\_work\194fdc7b9\Data Collection App - Release\drop\_PublishedWebsites\Cabi.FormsAdmin.Api_Package\DCA_API.zip' -setParamFile:'DCA_API.SetParameters.xml' -dest:auto,computerName='prerelweb4',userName='',password='',authType='ntlm',includeAcls='False' -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='WebServices (Secure)\FormsAdmin' -setParam:kind=DestinationVirtualDirectory,scope='WebServices (Secure)\\FormsAdmin',value='e:\cabi_sites\WebServices_Secure\FormsAdmin'  -allowUntrusted 
**2017-04-15T22:41:14.4909648Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Error: Could not find file ''DCA_API.SetParameters.xml''.**
2017-04-15T22:41:14.4909648Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Error count: 1.
2017-04-15T22:41:14.4909648Z Deployment to prerelweb4 complete`

Comment: Could you please post how you define the setParamFile in your task.json file of your custom build task  and where the `DCA_API.SetParameters.xml` locates?  Here is an extension that already developed maybe you could have a reference. https://github.com/rschiefer/MSDeployAllTheThings

Comment: The custom control is derived from MSDeployAllTheThings (with additional parameters and modified to support multiple server deployment).  task.json doesn't have a parameter to get setParamFile.  The location is being determined using the package location and replacing .zip with .SetParameters.xml.  The file is definitely there as I've checked.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using this task: [MSDeployAllTheThings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rschiefer.MSDeployAllTheThings). According to the logs, you are using it from Release. So you need to make sure that the "DCA_API.SetParameters.xml" file is published to artifact drop during the build and is also downloaded correctly during release. And then, you need to enter the absolute path in the Additional Arguments so that the task can find the file. For your scenario, if the "DCA_API.SetParameters.xml" file is placed in the same folder with "DCA_API.zip" file, you need to use this:

```
-setParamFile:"D:\BuildAgent\_work\194fdc7b9\Data Collection App - Release\drop\_PublishedWebsites\Cabi.FormsAdmin.Api_Package\DCA_API.SetParameters.xml"
```

I tried with absolute path at my side and didn't see any issue with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The settings file is in the same path as the zip package and I've used it with the absolute path and it says invalid path rather than file not found.  I've also manually checked and the file is definitely appearing in the folder.

Comment: @NeilD Can you share the logs when you use the absolute path?

Comment: @NeilD Also share a screenshot for your task settings in build definition if possible.